# Rank amateur needs help combining two tables

Tags: sql-server

The simplified version of my question is:

Say I have two tables. T1 contains the columns ID, C1, C2 and C3. Rows in this table represent complete records.

T2 contains the columns ID, C2 and C3. Rows in this table represent incomplete records.

Now, I want to create a view (V1) in which T1's data is replaced with data from T2 based on matching IDs.

Comment: Please specify what you mean by "UPDATE" in your case...

Comment: Please consider reading [this advice](https://dba.meta.stackexchange.com/questions/2976/help-me-write-this-query-in-sql)

Comment: updated => replaced with

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Something like:

```
SELECT T1.ID, T1.C1
     , COALESCE(T2.C2, T1.C2) AS C2
     , COALESCE(T2.C3, T1.C3) AS C3
FROM T1
LEFT JOIN T2
    ON T1.ID = T2.ID
```

If there is no matching row in T2, T2.Cn will be null, COALESCE maps this to T1.Cn

Comment: Almost .... C1 exists only in T1 ;-)

Comment: Ah, thanks. I'll update